# look ahead for non digit characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a `regex` which should extract the license plates from the text. For example, it should be able to extract `D-D 200`, `A-DEÜ34`,`A-DEÜ34` and `D-D200` from the following character sets:

```
1) D-D 200
2) A-DEÜ34.
3) A-DE34 on the fly
4) D-D200 my name is blah blah
```

but the following one is not an acceptable license plate number and extracting `D-D 200` from the following text is wrong:

```
1) D-D 200 200
```

What I am trying to do in my regex is to have a look ahead and check if the next characters are "space and a non-digit". But it seems that my code is not working properly.

Here is my regex:

```
//      between one to three letters:   [a-züäöA-ZÜÄÖ]){1,3})
//      a dash line                     \-   or a \\—
//      between one to three letters:   [a-zA-Z]){1,3}
//      zero or one space               (\s){0,1}
//      one to four letters             ([0-9]){1,4}
//      look ahead (?=)
//      look ahead for: space AND a non digit   \s\D
//              or dot or comma .|,
(([a-züäöA-ZÜÄÖ]){1,3})(\-|—)([a-züäöA-ZÜÄÖ]){1,3}((\s){0,1})([0-9]){1,4}(?=(\s\D|.|,))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is standalone `D-D 200` good but extracting it from `D-D 200 200` bad?

Comment: This would work `^\b[a-zA-Z]{1,3}-[a-zA-Z]{1,3} ?\d{1,4}\b(?=[ .]\D|$)` https://regex101.com/r/i9aYAy/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would assert that there has to a non digits at the right (except when there is a newline) then the first example `D-D 200` will not match by itself as there is no character after it to assert.

**Note** that `(\s\D|.|,)` is the same as `(\D)` as `\D` matches non digits, but if you don't need the capture groups you can omit them.

---

You can use a negative lookahead `(?![^\d\r\n]*\d)` to assert that there is not a digit following after the pattern.

```
[a-züäöA-ZÜÄÖ]{1,3}[-—][a-züäöA-ZÜÄÖ]{1,3}\s?[0-9]{1,4}(?![^\d\r\n]*\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QpDJCL/1)

A positive lookahead variant `(?=[^\d\r\n]*$)` could be to assert what is directly to the right is only non digits till the end of the string

```
[a-züäöA-ZÜÄÖ]{1,3}[-—][a-züäöA-ZÜÄÖ]{1,3}\s?[0-9]{1,4}(?=[^\d\r\n]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EC5F9I/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and the regex.
It works better than mine, but it's still not completly correct. It doesn't work for "pi-az 4415 lotende 33". The reason is that there is a digit in the next word(s).

Comment: In the meantime, is there anyway to let line break every where in the given string. For example, I would like to be able to correctly recognize "pi-az 4415" in the following string: "pi-
az 4415 lotende 33".

Comment: @user13578 Do you mean like this? `[a-züäöA-ZÜÄÖ]{1,3}[-—][a-züäöA-ZÜÄÖ]{1,3}\s?[0-9]{1,4}(?!\h*\d)`  https://regex101.com/r/t9HyJD/1 Or the other way around `[a-züäöA-ZÜÄÖ]{1,3}[-—][a-züäöA-ZÜÄÖ]{1,3}\s?[0-9]{1,4}(?=\h*[^\s\d]|$)` https://regex101.com/r/iqCcKY/1